# how to recover the saved images in a bagfile to jpg or png

Tags: sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag file with image sensor message how I can recover and save the images into the jpg or png files?

I appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27713/how-to-recover-the-saved-images-in-a-bagfile-to-jpg-or-png/) by [Eddit](https://answers.ros.org/users/1712/eddit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT: This answer was applicable back in the ROS Fuerte days of rosmake. I'd recommend checking out one of the other answers for any modern ROS version.

ORIGINAL:
I've successfully used this tutorial in the past to extract images / video from .bag files:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eddit](https://answers.ros.org/users/1712/eddit/) on 2012-02-15**:
In the example the bag file should be in a ros folder. Is it possible to locate the bag file in not ros folder and have the launch file in the same folder and find the bag file ?

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-02-15**:
Instead of $(find image_view)/test.bag you should be able to put a hard-coded absolute path to your bag file. I haven't tested that.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-09-02**:
Is there an option for png images?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the Python script below as a ROS node to convert a bag file to a set of images in a directory. To run I use:

```
rosrun my_package bag_to_images.py ../saved_images ../input.bag
```

where the `saved_images/` directory must exist beforehand. Also, give the location of `saved_images/` relative to the directory where the bag_to_images.py script is located. The `input.bag` file should also be specified relative to the directory where the bag_to_images.py script is located. It is possible to use this in a launch file but I never do that.

For each image topic just put another `if topic ==` section into the script and modify the topic names to match those in your bag file. The images get saved to `saved_images/right_{message timestamp}.pgm`. To save as .png or .jpg just change those lines to use those file extensions, as OpenCV is smart enough to figure out how to write the files the correct way. See [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) at the cv::imread section for supported formats with OpenCV.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Start up ROS pieces.
PKG = 'my_package'
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PKG)
import rosbag
import rospy
import cv
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

# Reading bag filename from command line or roslaunch parameter.
import os
import sys

class ImageCreator():
    # Must have __init__(self) function for a class, similar to a C++ class constructor.
    def __init__(self):
        # Get parameters when starting node from a launch file.
        if len(sys.argv) < 1:
            save_dir = rospy.get_param('save_dir')
            filename = rospy.get_param('filename')
            rospy.loginfo("Bag filename = %s", filename)
        # Get parameters as arguments to 'rosrun my_package bag_to_images.py <save_dir> <filename>', where save_dir and filename exist relative to this executable file.
        else:
            save_dir = os.path.join(sys.path[0], sys.argv[1])
            filename = os.path.join(sys.path[0], sys.argv[2])
            rospy.loginfo("Bag filename = %s", filename)

        # Use a CvBridge to convert ROS images to OpenCV images so they can be saved.
        self.bridge = CvBridge()

        # Open bag file.
        with rosbag.Bag(filename, 'r') as bag:
            for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages():
                if topic == "/left/image_raw":
                    try:
                        cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv(msg, "bgr8")
                    except CvBridgeError, e:
                        print(e)
                    timestr = "%.6f" % msg.header.stamp.to_sec()
                    image_name = str(save_dir)+"/left_"+timestr+".pgm"
                    #image_name = str(save_dir)+"/"+timestr+"_left"+".pgm"
                    cv.SaveImage(image_name, cv_image)
                if topic == "/right/image_raw":
                    try:
                        cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv(msg, "bgr8")
                    except CvBridgeError, e:
                        print(e)
                    timestr = "%.6f" % msg.header.stamp.to_sec()
                    image_name = str(save_dir)+"/right_"+timestr+".pgm"
                    #image_name = str(save_dir)+"/"+timestr+"_right"+".pgm"
                    cv.SaveImage(image_name, cv_image)

# Main function.    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize the node and name it.
    rospy.init_node(PKG)
    # Go to class functions that do all the heavy lifting. Do error checking.
    try:
        image_creator = ImageCreator()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [3XTR3M3](https://answers.ros.org/users/34236/3xtr3m3/) on 2018-03-20**:
I am confused between using header timestamp and normal timestamp. Would the file name have the timestamp when the image was captured or when the image was recorded. If it is the recorded one, can we change it to the time when it was captured or we need to publish another clock topic and then map.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-03-21**:
I don't know what you mean by the difference between captured and recorded. However, the image messages in the bag will have a header that has the timestamp of when the message was published. That published time will be the time used when generating the filename.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I modified Thomas D's answer for OpenCV version 2.

```
* All topics that contain a search term (desired_topic) are accepted.
* Option to include image index with leading zeroes (index_in_filename)
* Delimiter changed to '-' to avoid confusion with underscores in topic names.
* Support for compressed topics.
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Extract images from a bag file.
#
# Original author: Thomas Denewiler (http://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/)

# Start up ROS pieces.
PKG = 'my_package'
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PKG)
import rosbag
import rospy
import cv2
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

# Reading bag filename from command line or roslaunch parameter.
import os
import sys

class ImageCreator():

    image_type = ".jpg"
    desired_topic = "image_raw"
    index_in_filename = True
    index_format = "06d"
    image_index = 0

    # Must have __init__(self) function for a class, similar to a C++ class constructor.
    def __init__(self):
        # Get parameters when starting node from a launch file.
        if len(sys.argv) < 1:
            save_dir = rospy.get_param('save_dir')
            filename = rospy.get_param('filename')
            rospy.loginfo("Bag filename = %s", filename)
        # Get parameters as arguments to 'rosrun my_package bag_to_images.py <save_dir> <filename>', where save_dir and filename exist relative to this executable file.
        else:
            save_dir = os.path.join(sys.path[0], sys.argv[1])
            filename = os.path.join(sys.path[0], sys.argv[2])
            rospy.loginfo("Bag filename = %s", filename)

        # Use a CvBridge to convert ROS images to OpenCV images so they can be saved.
        self.bridge = CvBridge()

        # Open bag file.
        with rosbag.Bag(filename, 'r') as bag:
            for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages():
                topic_parts = topic.split('/')
                # first part is empty string
                if len(topic_parts) == 3 and topic_parts[2] == self.desired_topic:
                    try:
                        cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "bgr8")
                    except CvBridgeError, e:
                        print(e)
                    timestr = "%.3f" % msg.header.stamp.to_sec()
                    if self.index_in_filename:
                        image_name = str(save_dir) + "/" + topic_parts[1] + "-" + format(self.image_index, self.index_format) + "-" + timestr + self.image_type
                    else:
                        image_name = str(save_dir) + "/" + topic_parts[1] + "-" + timestr + self.image_type
                    cv2.imwrite(image_name, cv_image)
                    self.image_index = self.image_index + 1

# Main function.    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize the node and name it.
    rospy.init_node(PKG)
    # Go to class functions that do all the heavy lifting. Do error checking.
    try:
        image_creator = ImageCreator()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

---

Originally posted by [Tommi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23616/tommi/) with karma: 111 on 2016-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way I found was using "image_saver" tool of "image_view" package through the terminal. More details can be found at : http://wiki.ros.org/image_view.

example:  Play the *.bag file  and use "rosrun image_view image_saver image:=[your topic]"

similarly "video_recorder" tool can be used for extracting video.

---

Originally posted by [Gourav_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30034/gourav_kumar/) with karma: 11 on 2017-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1